# The new item using \item afte \quotation does not appear

Tags: enumerate, itemize, quotation

As you can see from the sample script below, the last item does not appear as an item, because I use \quotation before it. How to use quotation at the end of an item, and start a new item after it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} 

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item First item.
    \item Second item with multi-line quotation that I need in new line: \quotation{\lipsum[2-3]}
    \item THIS SHOULD BE A NEW ITEM BUT IT DOES NOT APPEAR AS A NEW ITEM
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: From where do you have that `\quotation` is a macro? It is not, it is an environment (aka proper use is `\begin{quotation}....\end{quotation}`

Answer (score 1):

`\quotation` is an environment that needs a proper end, use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} 

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item First item.
    \item Second item with multi-line quotation that I need in new line:
     \begin{quotation}
      \lipsum[2-3]
     \end{quotation}
    \item THIS SHOULD BE A NEW ITEM BUT IT DOES NOT APPEAR AS A NEW ITEM
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

and it works as expected